# Fitting a Python Scipy truncnorm model to observed values and then sampling

Tags: python, python-2.7, statistics, scipy, random

I am struggling with the Scipy truncnorm fit method and I would appreciate help so that the fitted parameter coefficients are consistent with the observed data.

As an example, I have created a small sample from the right hand tail of a N(0,1) distribution (where the observations are larger than 2 stdev) and have thrown in a few outliers.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

values = np.array([2.01,  2.06,  2.71,  2.31,  2.58,  2.17,  3.03,  2.24,  2.12,
                   2.72,  2.46,  2.66,  2.49,  3.41,  2.46,  2.12,  2.12,  2.65,
                   2.32,  2.49,  5.15,  2.62,  2.48,  2.27,  2.05])
pd.Series(values).describe()
```

This then produces the following summary statistics:

```
count    25.000
mean      2.548
std       0.633
min       2.01
25%       2.17
50%       2.46
75%       2.65
max       5.15
```

To illustrate the problem I am having with the scipy fit method and to better understand the truncnorm implementation, I have built the following intuitive models from inspecting the above summary statistics and sampled histograms to the observed values (see charts below). What I am struggling with is why the fit method gives such poor results when I attempt to sample using the estimated parameters? In the event I am not using the fit results correctly or making some other mistake, I would appreciate help with the transformations?

The code to build up these examples:

```
size = 10000
bins = 30
intuitive_models = {"model1":(2, 5),
                    "model2":(1, 4, 1),
                    "model3":(0.8, 4, 1, 1.25),
                    "fitted":truncnorm.fit(values)}

# store the tuncnorm random sample into a dict
model_results = dict()
for model, params in intuitive_models.items():
    model_results[model] = truncnorm(*params).rvs(size)

# plot the random sample vs the oserved values
for model, params in intuitive_models.iteritems():
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(model_results[model], bins=bins, normed=True)
    plt.title(model + ': ' + repr(params))
    plt.hist(values, normed=True, alpha=0.5)

# tabular comparison    
print pd.DataFrame(model_results).describe()
```

which produced the following tabular data:

```
             fitted        model1        model2        model3 
count  10000.000000  10000.000000  10000.000000  10000.000000 
mean       1.024707      2.372819      2.524923      2.698601 
std        0.014362      0.333144      0.443857      0.584215 
min        1.000019      2.000040      2.000007      2.000019 
25%        1.012248      2.121838      2.181642      2.245088 
50%        1.024518      2.280975      2.407814      2.557983 
75%        1.036996      2.534782      2.757778      2.998948 
max        1.049991      4.829619      4.982337      5.905201
```

Thanks Bertie.
p.s. I hope this is accepted as a coding question and not a stats question - which is why I have posted it here.

[image: model1]
[image: model2]
[image: model3]
[image: Fitted]

-- Update 28-Aug-2014 --
The idea with this post was to see get some help with the scipy.stats.truncnorm.fit method and in the couple of days, I have built my own clunky algorithm. From my discussions with Robert, I get the impression the R or standard implementation for truncnorm is to only take 3 parameters. For those coming to this post later, once scipy has an improved fitting engine, this is what I have estimated (assuming we want an asymptotic right tail).

[image]

Comment: Try computing the log likelihood of the data given each model (i.e. sum(log(p(x[i] | model parameters)))). If the fitting procedure is working as expected, you should find the log likelihood is greatest for the fitted model. I suspect (not sure) that you'll find the fitted model actually has a lesser log likelihood than the other models, which means there is some numerical problem -- perhaps the fitting function is stuck in local minimum or can't get off a nearly-flat plateau. Try multiple random initial values for the parameters and take the resulting fit which has greatest log likelihood.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I am not sure if I have done this right as its been quite a long time since I have done high level stats, but if I use the scipy minimise on the log-likelihood function, then are best parameters (for this dataset) for truncnorm = [1.671, 4.285, 0.0012, 1.201]?

Comment: That seems plausible, although I'm not sure what the four parameters are; I'm curious to know, as I would expect only 3 (namely mu, sigma, and cut-off point) but it's not essential that I know, only that you do. You can try plotting the log likelihood over some regions (e.g. make a contour plot in two dimensions, you'll have to pick specific values for any other parameter or parameters) and verify that the result you get from the log likelihood maximization agrees with any peak you see in the plot.

Comment: I have done some further work and have implemented a slightly better algorithm. I think [1.728, 3.999, -0.38 , 1.383] is a better fit for this data. Would be interesting to see if anyone with experience with R could confirm? FYI the scipy truncnorm function takes 2 truncation boundaries, one for the left tail and one for the right.

Comment: Those numbers can't be the parameters of a truncated normal, right? because the right-hand truncation must be greater than or equal to the maximum of the data. (I don't know in what order the parameters are specified; maybe you should say. But all of those are less than the maximum, namely 5.15, so none could be the right-hand truncation.) By the way, since you threw in some outliers, these data make the parameter fitting problem very interesting. I find the parameters to maximize the log likelihood actually have large negative mu and large sigma. I can post some numerical values, just ask.

Comment: Please note that I am using Python 2.7 and scipy. I have never before used truncnorm distribution and its been a long time since my stats and R programming. In Python, they define truncnorm with parameters (a, b, loc and scale). In the event you want to model this with an asymptotic right hand, then you can set b = np.Inf (i.e. there is then no limit on the right hand tail), in which case, the a parameter would probably be somewhere near 2. In my crusty optimiser, I have allowed the user to specify whether they need double-sided truncation. Appreciated if you could post your estimates? Thanks

Comment: Well, if b=3.999, then the value 5.15 in the data is impossible, right? For the negative log likelihood, the least value I've found is nll=9.5064 for a=2.01, b=5.15 (i.e., least and greatest values in data), location= -30.312, and scale=4.3073. Note that nll=14.351 for a=2, b=inf, location=0 and scale=1 (i.e., parameters from which all except outliers were drawn). Outliers change the max likelihood solution substantially. If you are really working with a distribution containing outliers, maybe you should try a mixture model, with one component for the ordinary data and one for the outliers.

Comment: Thanks for the estimates Robert. As I mentioned, I don't have much familiarity with truncnorm or scipy (sp), I have simply reversed out what each parameter means from intuition. FYI, in the sp implementation, the input truncation parameters then get translated by the loc and scale (i.e. scale > 1 makes the effective range wider). I think its quite a nice implementation - although I have not looked into the formal statistical definition. Do you have any pointers to a Python mixture implementation using some 'recognised' library (sklearn?) you can recommend? Thanks

Comment: OK, I see now that b=3.999 corresponds to 5.15 in untranslated values, so there's no problem there. I don't know a library in Python which has a mixture fitting algorithm. I'm sure there's one in R -- can you dump out the data, run R, and then read the results? If it must be in Python, an implementation of the expectation-maximization algorithm would be straightforward.